# Could not convert PHP value to type date. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, faker

I created fixtures with fakerphp to generate fake birth date but can't load fixtures files and getting this error message : Could not convert PHP value '1970-01-01' to type date. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime. Do you have an idea what I should modify please ?

Here is part of my php entity file code :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $birthDate;


public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getEmailAddress(): ?string
{
    return $this->emailAddress;
}

public function setEmailAddress(string $emailAddress): self
{
    $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;

    return $this;
}

public function getBirthDate(): ?string
{
    return $this->birthDate;
}

public function setBirthDate(string $birthDate): self
{
    $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

    return $this;
}
```

And my fixture :

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager):void
{
    $faker = Factory::create(('fr_FR'));
    $faker->seed(1234);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
        $member = new Member();

        $member->setEmailAddress('user@test.com');
        $member->setFirstName($faker->firstName());
        $member->setLastName($faker->lastName());
        $member->setbirthDate($faker->date($format ='Y-m-d', $max = '2004-31-12'));
        $member->setPostalAddress($faker->address());

        $password = $this->encoder->encodePassword($member, 'password');
        $member->setPassword($password);
    }

    $manager->persist($member);
    $manager->flush();
}
}
```

Comment: The `date` method creates a _string_ value. Use `$faker->dateTime` instead.

Comment: already try to use ```$faker->dateTime``` but still got an error : 
```App\Entity\Member::setBirthDate(): Argument #1 ($birthDate) must be of type string, DateTime given, called in /src/DataFixtures/MemberFixtures.php on line 35```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

birthDate type is 'date' and in your setter you give a String
you have to change your setter to this ->  `setBirthDate(\DateTimeInterface $birthDate){}`

Comment: Thank you so much!
I think I tried this before but should've update my getter too, to give ```\DateTimeInterface```type 
Code is alays details